# What local resources are used when bruteforcing a remote service?

Tags: passwords, brute-force, password-cracking

What pc resources are used when bruteforcing ? 
I mean bruteforcing something online, not hashes.
Do you need a good amount a RAM and a good CPU or it's just about the internet speed ?

Comment: *"I mean bruteforcing something online"* What, specifically? The answer may be different for bruteforcing a username/password login, versus bruteforcing credit card transactions, vs anything else.

Answer (score 27):

Well, unless the site you are bruteforcing is potato, it will have rate limits locking you out after a few attempts. So the biggest resource will be the number of IP addresses you can get, to circumvent the lockout. (assuming IP is used to block)

If there is no limit, then it will likely be internet speed. Though under some extremely rare circumstances, it may be something else.

Comment: One of the only "extremely rare circumstances" I can think of is having physical access to the network the servers are on to connect to it directly with Ethernet, but I think getting the hashes would be easier than that...

Comment: Well, I was actually thinking something like the SCRAM protocol, where the client has to do pbkdf2 on his end, or even a variant with argon2 with high memory usage.

Comment: Some sites will lock the account instead of blocking the IP after a number of tries. In that case, no amount of IP-addresses will help. You will also get no further with a supercomputer than a raspberry pi

Comment: @Suppen Yes, but that brings its own problems - it's basically a free DoS attack on the site. A simple "one login per second" is usually a lot better compromise between security and *actually being able to use the service* :D